# VBA code failing due to runtime error 1004 Microsoft excel cannot paste the data

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting runtime error 1004 Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data
in the following code. I had been running a copy and paste picture routine for some time and all of a sudden Excel starting giving me this run time error. It had been working fine for several days until now (no OS update or reboot). Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    r = "Business Mobile List - July 2017"
    Filename = Application.InputBox("Enter Filename:", "Business Mobile 
    FileName", r)
    If (Filename <> "") Then
    xlFile = "D:\try\big file vba\" & Filename
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk = XL.Workbooks.Open(xlFile)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

         dateS = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        dateString = Application.InputBox("Enter A Date: (Format dd-mm-yyyy)", 
         dateS, dateS)
         TheDate = DateValue(dateString)

          With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = wbk.Sheets("Stuck orders").Cells(.Rows.Count, 
         "B").End(xlUp).Row
           End With


               For i = 2 To LastRow
              If (wbk.Sheets("Stuck orders").Cells(i, 19) = TheDate) Then
               wbk.Sheets("Stuck orders").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy

               erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
               ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
               **ActiveSheet.Paste** 'error occured while pasting
               ActiveWorkbook.Save
              Application.CutCopyMode = False
                   End If

               Next i
          MsgBox "Fileuploaded"
           wbk.Save
            wbk.Close
           Application.CutCopyMode = False

                  Else
              MsgBox "File does not exist"
                End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you opening the other workbook in a different instance of Excel?

Comment: And why are you calculating `LastRow` using `wbk.Sheets("Stuck orders").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`?  If the active sheet is in a new format file, and `wbk` is referring to an old format file, that will crash out due to the difference in the number of rows permitted in the two file formats.

Comment: Hi.. I am calculating it to run the loop and copy all the data that matches with the date I am giving...i will change the loop  but why it is failing while copying the data  could you please help

Comment: OK, to help I need two things (1) Why are you opening another instance of Excel for the second workbook?  Why can't you use the current instance? (2) Why are you calculating `LastRow` using information from two different worksheets (i.e. the active one, and the one in the other workbook)?  The answers to those two questions will possibly (probably?) affect the way to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi I am opening Business Mobile List - July 2017 which is available in different folder  and I am calculating the last row of the same file to run the loop and copy the data in my current file the last row I have used  to calculate total no. of rows in Business Mobile List - July 2017